# jquery popup problem

Tags: jquery

i am a nobe to jquery..what i am trying to do is when i click on the register button on my index i want a popup to include my register.php on the upper-right corner i have been trying the whole day but cant firgure it out i tried to use include "register.php" in  ![enter image description here][1]

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you'd post some code - just the snippet of jQuery you've tried and the HTML for your theoretical popup - is it created on the fly?  A hidden div?  How is it styled?

Comment: When you say "popup", what do you mean? A "lightbox" style popup? A new browser window? Does the popup need to be draggable?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you actually want a popup, you want a hidden form to to display in the upper right corner that will post off to your register.php

```
<div id = "registerForm" style = "display: none; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; z-index: 9000">
  <form action = "register.php" method = "post">
     <!-- your registration fields here -->
  </form>
</div>
```

And then to make it display your button would look like this (using jQuery):

```
<input type = "button" onclick = "$('#registerForm').show();" value = "Register for my awesome site!"/>
```

Comment: thx for helping i did it finally but now i now i have a problem with aligning it to the top right corner and i have another problem with the select i am taking the value of slide from it so i cant remove it but still there is a combo box appearing that i dont want